# My android app is not rceiving OTP for phone verification from firebase phone auth

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

The exception message shows

> com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [App validation failed]Failed

Firstly There is no problem with the package name.

I have provided two SHA-1 keys one for debugging and another for release.
In the debug version app is getting OTP but for the release, the problem is occurring.

I generated SHA-1 for release using `keytool -list -v -keystore "key store path" -alias "key alias"` this.

Cant figure out the problem.

<s>**UPDATE**</s>

I used two flavours in my app

```
productFlavors {
    lite {

    }
    pro {

    }
}
```

When I removed these flavours the OTP is working fine

Comment: which SHA-1 key you saved in firebase console ?

Comment: both (debug and release)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue has been resolved.

The problem was occurring because of SHA-1 as I mentioned in the question. I was generating SHA-1 from my computer and (the process was perfectly fine) and uploading that on `Firebase Console`. After uploading the app to play store because of `Play Store App Signing` the SHA-1 fingerprint was getting changed.

> I had to take the SHA-1 from play console